# MainActivity.cs is not in sync with Main.axml in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I am new to development in Xamarin Studio and have been stuck on this issue for a little bit.  Whenever I make changes to my Main.axml file, the changes I make are not recognized when I run the app or when I try to access a new widget in my MainActivity.cs file.  For example I changed the background color of a button to red as well as the text and when I run the app I still get the default view.

Does anybody know how to sync the newly updated Main.axml file with it's matching C# file?  Thank you for the help ahead of time.

Comment: Did you use SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);?

Comment: Try doing a clean and rebuild to force all code changes to be picked up.